# hard lemma from a paper

Tags: representation-theory

I was reading a paper, there its mentioned as lemma that :

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let $\phi_1 : G\to GL(V)$ is a irreducible representation of $G$ and $\phi_2 : H \to GL(U)$ is a irreducible representation of $H$. Let $Z$ be centralizer of $H$ in $\mathbb{C}[G]$. Now define an action of $Z$ on $Hom_{H} (U,V)$ as follows, $(g.f)(u)=g(f(u))$ for all $g\in Z,f\in Hom_{H}(U,V)$. Show that under this action $Hom_{H}(U,V)$ is an irreducible representation of $Z$

I don't understand how to prove it, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer on. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Comment: I'm completely clueless, so couldn't do anything.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220623/centralizer-of-mathbbcg-in-mathbbch/1220739